# Google custom/programmable search: "Server: ESF"

Tags: search, google-api

I wrote a little Python program that issues Google custom/programmable API search queries at `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1`

The program works fine; no issues.

However, when the program prints out the HTTP response headers, I see the following:

> Server: ESF

Now, I expected to see:

> Server: gws

(the 'normal) Google Web Server

Does anyone know what ESF means here and why Google specifies ESF as its server?